Azure: How to trigger a network-restricted Logic App from Azure Data Factory
The problem
I need to trigger a Logic App workflow (Standard model) with a HTTP-request from an instance of Azure Data Factory (ADF). However, my organization requires me to restrict network access to the Logic App so if I use the pre-generated URL for the trigger, the request gets blocked. So how do I configure the pipeline in ADF so that the workflow gets triggered?
What I have tried
Our setup for the Azure resources is as follows:

public network access for the Logic App is disabled
the System Managed Identity of the ADF instance has the "Contributor" role for the Logic App
there's a private endpoint set up for the Logic App from ADF

To call the HTTP trigger from a Web activity in ADF I used the following parameters:

URL: Callback URL of the Logic App workflow, without the SAS token part
(pattern: https://<logicAppName>.azurewebsites.net:443/api/<workflowName>/triggers/manual/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0)
Method: POST
Body: "foo": "bar" (dummy value to satisfy ADF's requirement for a valid body in a POST request)
Authentication: System Assigned Managed Identity
Resource: https://management.azure.com
Headers:

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>



Returns
This call returns the following error code and message:
DirectApiInvalidAuthorizationScheme: The provided authorization token is not valid. The request should have a valid authorization header with 'Bearer' scheme.
Anyone has an idea how to do this?

have you checked this sample https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/synapse-or-adf-pipeline-access-logic-app-within-private-network/ba-p/3955324
I do not think you need set header here.

Yes, I had read that. But actually re-visiting that tutorial, I began from scratch and changed all the params one by one. And finally found a way in which it's working. So thanks a lot, @wenbo! Will post an answer.

the key part is to have an ir in the same vnet; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint

Using a bearer authentication and System-assigned identity is a total overkill; the solution is much simpler:

Use the original callback-URL including the SAS token (https://<logicAppName>.azurewebsites.net:443/api/<workflowName>/triggers/manual/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=<sasToken>)
Method: POST
Body: dummy body
Authentication: None
Headers: None
Integration runtime: Use an IR that exists in the same virtual network as the Logic App.

